# Count number of columns using firstRecord.size() in CSV?

Tags: java, csv

how to find number of columns in CSV?

Code to read CSV:

```
        CSVParser parser = new CSVParser(
                new FileReader(CSV_IMPORT_PATH), CSVFormat.DEFAULT
                .withFirstRecordAsHeader()
                .withIgnoreHeaderCase()
                .withTrim()
        );
        List<CSVRecord> list = parser.getRecords();
        System.out.println(firstRecord.size()); //NOT WORKING
```

i want to use this size to declare 2 dimensional array within CSVRecord loop...
Please help,
Jacek

Comment: How is this related to `apache-poi`?

Comment: this is part of apache poi librabray

Comment: No, it part of apache commons.

Answer (score 1):

Use List headers = parser.getHeaderNames();

headers.size() will be count of headers

This method is available Since: 1.7 make sure your lib version is greater than this